# Installing WebOrb for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, weborb

I'm trying to install WebOrb for Rails.

In a new test Rails 3 project, I do:

```
rails plugin install http://themidnightcoders.net:8089/svn/weborb
```

but all I get back is

```
Plugin not found ["http://themidnightcoders.net:8089/svn/weborb"]
```

Variations on the url also return the same error. Is there some sort of connection issue on my end, or is the resource down?

Answer (score 1):

WebORB for Rails is just not compatible with Rails 3. According to [this comment](http://dcdror.riaforge.org/blog/index.cfm/2009/10/9/Using-the-plugin-from-FlashBuilder4#c355E5CE8-E0E3-CDBD-43B9A1E138689F5D) there are no plans to start porting WebORB for Rails 3.